# how to add a second random variable in mixed effects model in r

Tags: r

I want to run a mixed effects model with two random factors using `lme4::lmer`:

```
lmer(minpH ~ vetg + `VET EIWIT ratio` +(1|proefcode), data = phase_data_compleet)
lmer(minpH ~ vetg + `VET EIWIT ratio` +(1|cow), data = phase_data_compleet)
```

These two codes do work seperately, but i want a code where `proefcode` and `cow` are both in the same model.
I have tried several thing like `(1|proefcode, cow)` and `(1|proefcode + cow)`, those do not work. I get the next error message:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "lmer(minpH ~ vetg + `VET EIWIT ratio` +(1|cow,"
```

and

```
Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, cow + experiment In addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(cow, experiment) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factord
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

```
lmer(minpH ~ vetg + `VET EIWIT ratio` + (1|proefcode) + (1|cow), data = phase_data_compleet)
```

Comment: Thank you Laterow, is it also possible to indicate that the random effect of cow is within the random effect of proefcode? because some cows are present in in several proefcodes. for example cow 94 is in proefcode 1 and 2, how to indicate that r will know that the random effect of cow 94 must be taken in proefcode 1 and proefcode 2 seperately?

Comment: Well, that depends a bit, but maybe this question + answer address that: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified

Comment: thanks again, the link does answer my question.